Is there anyway to resume "stuck" cmd.exe in windows 10?
For a lack of a better description, look at this screenshot:

Sometimes, after an out of memory semi-crash, cmd windows remain in this state.
If I click on them, nothing happens.
(some of them work and open, but others stay in this state)
The program run from these windows are still running.
It's like the "host" of the window crashed.
Obviously if I close them, they close and kill their spawned programs.
I wish there was a way to resume them.
Addendum:
This happebned to me already a few times in the past.
It's like some reference or "father" process is dead and the windows associated with it are unresponsive (as windows, but the processes running inside them are still alive)
Also some wsl "bash" windows are affected but no other windows are affected.. so I think it must be some "shell host" or similar process associated with those windows.
But I don't know more than that.
From past experience I know that if I kill them one by one, every new window (command prompt or bash) work without problems.
I am curious if there is any way to regain control of those windows.
Another example:

The two windows on the left are responsive, but the 3 on the right are not. They don't pop up when clicking on them or using alt+tab or task manager.
I am 99% positive that the problem relies in CONHOST.

the first thing I'd try is to kill the desktops explorer.exe process, and let it respawn. worth a try

I would change how the child programs spawn. Using start "" program.exe you can effectively start the program, then immediately return focus back to the cmd window, and if this is done in a batch script, the cmd window just closes.

@FrankThomas I did that. this is a problem happened to me before... every new window works, but the old ones (before an out of memory half-crash) are unresponsive as windows but what is running inside them is still working.

@LPChip I explained better the problem.

do an sfc /scannow this might fix the issue

And I explained a possible workaround that may stop the problem from even happening.

@Maslie that's not the problem. after a windows out of memory something crashes and causes this problem.

@LPChip no. you misunderstood the whole thing. but thanks anyhow.

No, I did understand you. Your computer runs out of memory, which freezes the windows. My suggestion eliminates having the windows open. Keeping the windows open may lead to the out-of-memory, so my suggestion is to use start so that the windows don't have to remain open.

I understood. And I know that. But my question is if there is a way to resume those stuck sessions, not how to prevent that.

also... I want the shells open, not a program run from command line but the shell itself. the problem is clearly related to CONHOST. and the best way to prevent that is to use linux :P
